# Can I include recipes in Chef deployment hooks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, opsworks

It might just be me doing something horribly wrong, but I seem to be unable to use custom recipes in Chef / AWS OpsWorks deploy hooks:

```
# before_symlink.rb
include_recipe 'supervisor'
```

OpsWorks deploy fails with the following error:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
No resource or method named `include_recipe' for `Chef::Provider::Deploy::Timestamped ""'
```

We're using Chef 11.10. Any ideas why this might be happening?

**Update:**

We're using [this cookbook](https://github.com/poise/supervisor). The default recipe installs Supervisord, and so far it's working OK. We run that during the Setup phase.

Trouble comes when attempting to use the `supervisor_service` resource from the same cookbook during the deploy hook. The error message in this case is:

```
    No resource or method named `supervisor_service' for
```

The first error described above comes when attempting to include the recipe using `include_recipe`.

Answer (score 0):

OpsWorks 'deploy' is a custom AWS addon to Chef and doesn't support the full set of Chef functionality.

Installing supervisord doesn't feel like something that should be deploy-time anyway -- that should be a instance-build-time action, though you might need to perform a service action and deploy-time such that you'd make your cookbook 'depends' on supervisord and have your deploy hook call the necessary resource.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, supervisord is being installed at the Setup stage using the default recipe of this cookbook: https://github.com/poise/supervisor. What we're having trouble with is the configuration during deploy time, as you suggest.

The question is: how can I depend on another cookbook from a deploy hook? As I understand it, deploy hooks do not belong to a cookbook, do they? Where is the `depends` sentence expected to be placed?

Comment: It would go in metadata.rb.  What happens when you call the supervisor LWRP's during the hook w/o an include_recipe?

Comment: Without a `metadata.rb`, calling the supervisor LWRP from the hook produces the error message `No resource or method named 'supervisor_service' for [...]`. I have updated the question to include more detail as I didn't explain myself properly. I'll try this using a metadata file and see what happens.